# Integer Conversion for Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, type-conversion

I've been trying to brush up on my C recently and was writing a program to manually parse through a PNG file.

I viewed the PNG file in a hex editor and noticed a stream of bytes that looked like

```
00 00 00 0D
```

in hex format.

This string supposedly represents a length that I am interested in.

I used `getc(file)` to pull in the bytes of the PNG file.

I created a char array as

```
char example[8];
```

to store the characters retrieved from `getc`.

Now, I have populated `example` and printing it with

```
printf("%#x, %#x, %#x, %#x", example[0]....
```

shows `0, 0, 0, 0xd` which is exactly what I want.

However when I use

```
int x = atoi(example)
```

or

```
int x = strtol(example, NULL, 16)
```

I get back zero in both cases (I was expecting 13). Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atoi` converts strings like `"0"` to its numeric equivalent, in this case `0`. What you have instead is the string `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\r"` which is nowhere near numeric characters.

If you want to interpret your bytes as a number you could do something like

```
char example[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0xd};
printf("%d\n", *(uint32_t*) example);
```

You will notice (in case you're using a x86 CPU) that you will get `218103808` instead of `13` 
due to little endianness: the farther you go right the more significant the number gets.

As [PNG uses big endian](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#7Integers-and-byte-order) you can simply use [`be32toh`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/be64toh/) (big endian to host endianess):

```
uint32_t* n = example;
printf("%u\n", be32toh(*n)
```

Comment: +1 For the best way to read the data `be64toh(*n)`.  Note: [PNG length fields are 32 bit.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#5Chunk-layout)

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` and `strtol` expect text strings, while you have an array of binary values. To combine the individual bytes in an array to a larger integer, try something like:

```
uint32_t x = (a[0] << 24) | (a[1] << 16) | (a[2] << 8) | a[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

atoi etc. operates on (ascii) strings.
You would get 123 for "123", which is in bytes 49 50 41 0.
What you have instead is binary 00 00 00 7B ... (well, endianess matters too).

*Simple, but in this case wrong solution (ignoring endianess):

Cast the array address to `int*` and then get a value with `*`.*

As integers in PNG are supposed to be big endian in any case,
the pointer casting would only work with big endian machines.
As portable solution, shifting the bytes with 24,16,8,0 and binary-or´ing them will do.

Comment: Do not do this, as it has hardware-dependent results. The PNG spec should say what byte order it actually uses (assuming it uses more than one byte).

Comment: That´s why i wrote "i have no idea what this PNG data thing is". Looked it up in the meantime: BE. Editing...